# AC input buck converter output ground oscillating

Tags: power-electronics, buck

Attached the buck converter complete circuit. It is working fine and the output voltage is staying constant.

But, just before the mosfet is turned on, the `out_gnd` node is oscillating.
Why is this happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Andy already answered your question below, but for your information, if you are in DCM as in your example, you can cheat your way out of a little bit of switching losses and perhaps EMI if you trigger your next on pulse in the valley of the oscillation, called valley switching. No requirement on it, just a small trick.

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding something, but I find it odd that your `in_gnd` net is connected to a gnd symbol. My guess is that this is ignored because the net has an explicit name. Then again, it also seems that the other side of C2 should be connected to the anodes of D4 and D2, not the `in_gnd` net. I guess some more-or-less stable voltage will form across C2, so the circuit will work in simulation, but please double-check if this is really intended.

Comment: @wrtlprnft my bad i messed it up after simulation. I thought of adding net labels for clarity just for this post. Simulation and question is still valid. Thank you so much for pointing this. I'll fix the schematic and repost...

Comment: @wrtlprnft fixed thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *just before the MOSFET is turned on, the out_gnd node is oscillating.
> Why is this happening?*

It begins oscillating after the MOSFET turns off and the diode is no longer conducting; residual energy in the inductor forms a tuned circuit with the MOSFET drain-source capacitance and, this will take some time to decay to zero. Of course, your switching cycle re-starts before it decays to zero hence, you see an oscillating waveform.

Do not fear the oscillating waveform; it will do no harm. It is natural and expected.